# privacy feature in 12.04 doesnt work?

Tags: unity

I noticed my recent documents folder is showing recent activity.So I go to system settings,click privacy,set it to all for forget activity,click delete history and set record to off.Long story short it doesnt work.When I open privacy up again it s set to default settings once again.Anyone know how to fix this ?it s not erasing recent history as well

Comment: I have the same issue. I excluded the folder in which I store my financially related documents. When I open the general dash I still get folders within the excluded folder to show up listed under "recently used"! 

Also with "recently downloaded" - there's a hidden folder inside the "Downloads" folder ".torrents" - I don't want my torrent files to show up here and I want all hidden folders excluded (including their content and subfolders!) ... 

Thanks for asking the question!